# Launch chat with user in MS Teams Android app from my android app

Tags: android, android-intent, microsoft-teams

I have an Android app, where a tap on a button should launch Microsoft Teams Android app and open a chat with a pre-defined user.

Is it possible to do and if yes - how?

Comment: Inspect Teams' Manifest file and look for `intent-filter`

Comment: thanx! that was a key to find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know user's E-Mail with which he/she is registered in MS Teams (ex: `username@email.com`), you can directly open chat with him/her using one of two options:

1. show user a chooser sheet with a choice to open chat in MS Teams Android app or one of web browsers:

   ```
   val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
       Uri.parse("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=username@email.com"))

   if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
       startActivity(sendIntent)
   }
   ```
2. force open chat with user in MS Teams Android app. Same as above, but substitute in Uri `https` with `msteams`:

```kotlin
Uri.parse("msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=username@email.com")
```

Comment: Is there any way to open chat and start call automatically?

Comment: No, this is not possible. 
Please see the answer in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63918326/ms-teams-starting-a-call-from-an-android-app