# MS Teams - Starting a call from an Android app

Tags: android, microsoft-teams

I would like to know if it is possible to start a MS Teams call from an Android application?
If so, where can I find an example intent to start the call?

I only found [this instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-uris/androidcall)  regarding starting calls in Skype for Business and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60788098/launch-chat-with-user-in-ms-teams-android-app-from-my-android-app) regarding starting chats in MS Teams, but I can't found anything regarding starting calls in MS Teams.

Comment: As of now we don't have any deeplink that will initailate call , You can use [calling bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to initiate a call.

Answer (score 2):

At this time they've created the deeplink to start a call, the syntax is:

**Audio Call**
`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>`

**Video Call**
`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>&withVideo=true`

Hope this can help someone actually.
**The documentation for these deeplinks:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generate-a-deep-link-to-a-call